# Using lapply to recode variables and paste an index number

Tags: r

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to use `lapply` to recode several variables while pasting in the last value of the variable name into the string.

Building on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396392/using-seq-along-paste-to-recode-in-a-loop), I know that I can recode several variables at a time:

`d2 <- lapply(d1, FUN=function(X) recode(X, "'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat'; 'Not interested' = 'No'"))`

But, what I need to do is slightly different. Suppose that my data frame has sequentially labeled variables, e.g. `var_1`, `var_2`, `var_3` and looks like this:

```
    var_1              var_2               var_3                   var_4
1:                                                                                
2: Somewhat interested Somewhat interested Somewhat interested      Not interested
3: Somewhat interested Somewhat interested Somewhat interested      Not interested
4:      Not interested Somewhat interested Somewhat interested Somewhat interested
```

I want to recode the variable and append the sequential identifier of the column name:

```
           var_1              var_2              var_3             var_4
1:                                                                            
2:         Somewhat 1         Somewhat 2         Somewhat 3               No 4
3:         Somewhat 1         Somewhat 2         Somewhat 3               No 4
4:               No 1         Somewhat 2         Somewhat 3         Somewhat 4
```

Thoughts on how to combine `recode` and `paste` together?

Comment: `lapply(seq_along(d1), FUN=function(X)
  paste(car::recode(d1[,X], "'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat'; 'Not interested' = 'No'"), X))`

Comment: Thanks @user20650. Could you help me understand the proper way to select a subset within d1?

Comment: if i understand you, to apply this to , for example, the second and fourth columns you would do `d2[c(2,4)] <- lapply(c(2,4), FUN=...as before)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the column names themselves for the `sapply()` (instead of `lapply()` - i had to remake the data by hand so this works with the version i have).

So

```
d2 <- lapply(d1, FUN=function(X) recode(X, "'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat'; 'Not interested' = 'No'"))
```

turns into

```
d2 <- sapply(colnames(d1), FUN=function(X) recode(d1[,X], "'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat'; 'Not interested' = 'No'"))
```

where `d1[,X]` is calling the column to apply the function to.

now to append the column suffix we can use `paste0()`

```
"'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat'; 'Not interested' = 'No'"
```

is replaced by

```
paste0("'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat ",X ,"'; 'Not interested' = 'No ", X,"'")
```

however this stil doesnt do exactly what you want since you will have the suffix and the prefix.

This means we need to then remove the prefix and we can use `substr()` for that.

```
substr(X, 5, nchar(X))
```

all together now:

```
d2 <- sapply(colnames(d1), FUN=function(X) recode(d1[,X],  paste0("'Somewhat interested' ='Somewhat ",substr(X, 5, nchar(X)) ,"'; 'Not interested' = 'No ", substr(X, 5, nchar(X)),"'")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regex:

```
mtx1 <- sapply(seq_along(df), function(x){gsub('interested', x, df[,x])})
mtx1
#      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        
# [1,] "Somewhat 1" "Somewhat 2" "Somewhat 3" "Not 4"     
# [2,] "Somewhat 1" "Somewhat 2" "Somewhat 3" "Not 4"     
# [3,] "Not 1"      "Somewhat 2" "Somewhat 3" "Somewhat 4"
```

Admittedly it leaves "Not" instead of "No", but you can either use more complicated regex, or just change it separately:

```
apply(mtx1, 2, function(x){gsub('Not', 'No', x)})
#      [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        
# [1,] "Somewhat 1" "Somewhat 2" "Somewhat 3" "No 4"      
# [2,] "Somewhat 1" "Somewhat 2" "Somewhat 3" "No 4"      
# [3,] "No 1"       "Somewhat 2" "Somewhat 3" "Somewhat 4"
```

Wrap with `as.data.frame` (or your favorite version) if you need data.frames instead of matrices.

Note that if you data is in factors, it will be more efficient to run the same regex on the levels instead of the actual data.

Comment: Could you help me understand how to do this on a subset of data? I'm struggling to find how to apply `seq_along` to a set number of columns..

Comment: Since a data.frame is a list, it's `length` is the number of columns, and `seq_along(df)` returns a sequence for indexing columns from `1:ncol(df)` (which is equivalent, if you prefer). If you need to index rows, you can use something like `seq_along(df$Var_1)`. After that, it's just a matter of keeping track of what sort of data your function will get (a single number in the `sapply` above; a vector in the `apply`), and writing the function accordingly.

Comment: @roody seq_along just generates a sequence of numbers which are then used for the df[,x] (this is what subsets your column).

user20650 already said in a comment before that using c(1:10) would go over columns 1 to 10 (This then would replace seq_along()).